# Copy/paste is not working in VMware (Ubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, vmware, copy-and-paste

Suddenly copy/paste stopped working from/to Windows10 host computer to/from UbuntuVM. Ubuntu restart did not help.

Regards,
Keff